# Return type of function-template not const T&?

Tags: c++, function, templates

In the example below the type of the instantiation `f<int&>(a)` is reported to be `int&`.

```
template<typename T>
const T& f(const T& x) {
    return x;
}

int main() {
    int a{0};
    decltype(f<int&>(a))::_;
}
```

But why is the type not `const int&` ?.

Edit:
The question is also why `f<int&>(0)` gives `x` as `int&` and not as `const int&`?

Comment: References are already const. Maybe you meant `f<int>(a)`

Comment: No. I mean the return-type of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References themselves cannot be `const`-qualified (only the type they reference can), so `const` is ignored in `const T` if `T` is a reference type.

References-to-references also don't exist. The reference collapsing rules say that trying to form a lvalue references to lvalue reference to type `U` will form a lvalue reference to type `U`.

So in the end, if `T` is a lvalue reference type, `const T&` is the same type as `T`, in your case `int&`.

There isn't really a point to having the template argument be a reference and having the return value be a reference to the template parameter. You probably just want `f<int>(a)` instead of `f<int&>(a)`. (Although you haven't said *why* you are interested in the behavior of `f<int&>`.)